# Почему не могу подключиться к локальному серверу PostgreSql из java?

Tags: java, postgresql

Добрый день.
Не могу подключиться из java к локальному серверу PostgreSql. Компьютер на винде. Есть ещё удалёный сервер на Ubuntu - к нему подключается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.
Вот лог:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ���� ������ "links" �� ����������
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:691)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:156)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at ru.ysoft.links_crawler.data.manage.DataBaseHelper.connect(DataBaseHelper.java:28)
    at ru.ysoft.links_crawler.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдите лог PostgreSQL - там будет внятное сообщение об ошибке. Логи лежат в директории `data/pg_log`.

На Windows это будет что-то вроде: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log`